# Passing List from MVC Core to client side so JavaScript can verify it

Tags: javascript

I am sorry if my title is not clear. I just can't think of the correct keyword and cant find the answer. Basically what I want to do is. I have something like this basically,

```
   foreach(var i in listOfName) {
     if(name[1].value != i) {
       then
       }
   }
```

However, that listOfName data must be send from the Controller. So what I meant is that when the HttpGet is load, I want to send list of Name from Controller to the View so in the view I can retrieve the ListOfName and do the verification.

Can someone point me how to do it or refer me to the existing therad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller Method

```
public JsonResult GetList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<"Name"> _list = new List<"Name">();
            _list =DB.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(_list , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

View

```
var url = '/TestController/testMethod';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
       $.each(data._list, function(k, v) {
          /// do stuff
        });
    });
```

View Bag

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag._list)
 {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BranchName)<br/>                    
    </td>
</tr>}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wondering, does that in the client side I the list will be named as "_list" thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry If I ask too much question. May I know the 'TestController/testMethod', Is it suppose to be '/Home/GetList' ? also is it possible to use ViewBag or TempData to solve this problem?

Comment: you can use ViewBag or TempData in  view method

Comment: Yes you can use Viewbag, TempData or ViewData to send data from controller to your view.

Comment: @JaniDevang I am planning to do var listOfName = ViewBag.Names but it seems to be not working properly. Any idea? :(

Comment: You should Set viewbag in View Method not in /Home/GetList.

Comment: @deepudileep Yes, I did but its still not working. hmm

Comment: you should display list in razor view

Comment: please see the answer

Comment: @Karyon2 which return type you are using, like JsonResult or ActionResult which one?

Comment: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag._list))';  You will get data into a jquery function